# Using OnDraw() Function in Android Conditionally

Tags: java, android

I want to know if we can  call Ondraw() method of Android conditionally based on some flag. For example `ondraw()` should be called only when a particular frame is decoded.

Consider this situation:

```
decoder();  /// @NDK 

set flag;   

if (Flag==set)

{

OnDraw() works and displays an image

}       

else

OnDraw sleeps;
```

Can we implement such type of activities in Android, if yes then how?

Comment: what you are looking for is View.invalidate(). onDraw will only be called if an invalidate was issued beforehand.

Comment: Thanks. In my case the pause for ondraw() would be only in few mili seconds-just for the duration the frame is being decoded- (and that too will be different for differenet frames) do I still use View.invalidate()?

Comment: I think you should test it out. I've gotten consistently 50-60 frames for my custom views where i was invalidating directly inside onDraw. But if it doesn't work for your constraints then you need to switch to something more complex like a SurfaceView with a dedicated render thread..

Comment: @Renard This makes sense. Could you please post a small pseudo code or a sample code demonstrating the use view.invalidate()? That will real help me understand better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you requested some sample code. 
I imagine you have a custom view in your layout which displays the decoded frames. In principle it could look like this:

```
class FrameView extends View {

    private Bitmap mBitmap;

    public FrameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Your drawing logic
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,0,0, null);
    }

    private void setFrame(final Bitmap b){
        if (mBitmap!=null){
            mBitmap.recycle();
        }
        mBitmap = b;
        //trigger onDraw, if this method is not called from a ui thread switch to postInvalidate()
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

You grab a handle to this View by calling findViewById() in your activity. Then in your decode thread you call setFrame on the view. Take care to use postInvalidate() if setFrame is called from outside the UI-thread.